# Variable visibility when thread terminates

Tags: java

Could somebody please tell me whether or not the visibility of member variables is guaranteed when a worker thead returns and terminates normally; is a volatile write/read sequence still required in order to guarantee visibility?

Comment: which and whose member variables?

Comment: If a worker thread is used to initialised the member variables of an object, is the main UI thread guaranteed to see the worker thread initialisations when the worker thread completes or are they lost in the worker thread's cache unless I explicitly enforce a memory barrier (e.g. via a volatile write/read sequence).

Answer (score 1):

After thread `t2` detects that thread `t1` has terminated, through `t1.isAlive()` or `t1.join()`, any writes in `t1` is visible to `t2`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4